# Use Hash Code Cookie for a subdomain or directory

Tags: php, testing, hash

I copied my code in my dev.domain.com path. But i want to use this method for only reach by me to /dev directory. I planned this, write a parameter like dev.domain.com?hash=h1g24j45kjjjkhj this going to make cookie. And I will enter directory with this.

I hope you will understand.

Thanks.

Comment: This makes no sense. If you want restricted access, you should use directory protection like .htaccess.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. Can you tell me how can i do this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Revent proposed, use .htaccess.

**1)** Create a `.htaccess` file in the folder you want to protect and put the following code in it:

```
AuthName "Got root ?" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile C:\wamp\.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

Change `AuthUserFile` to a path that isn't accessible from the internet.

**2)** Create a `.htpasswd` file (in this case in `C:\wamp\`) and add the following (change the values):

```
username:password
```

Now when a user tries to access that folder, a login prompt will show up !